# Bucket function: Not all available items can be selected/ are not shown

Tags: bucket

I would like to merge several positions with the help of the "bucket" function. Unfortunately I cannot select all available positions for the bucket. In my case these are cost centers. However, after creation the bucket these cost centers are displayed separately next to the bucket. Why are the missing positions not shown in the bucket function? All other cost centers are available.

Comment: What Salesforce product are you using?

Comment: Salesforce lightning

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many options, only 200 will be displayed.

[image]

As the message says, you can either use the search to narrow the options down, or add them manually.

In order to add them manually without searching, just click on the button `Enter Values` and type the values in (one value per line).

Then pick an existing bucket or give a name to a new one and click `Done`

Comment: I have already tried adding it manually. But the cost center was still not integrated.

Comment: Try searching for it and selecting it in the search box. then you are sure to pick the good one ;)

Comment: unfortunately not.. Is ist possible to attach screenshots?